# Can Not Get @Component As A Bean In Unit Test For Spring Boot Application with Apache Camel

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-camel, components, javabeans

I am doing unit test for my Spring Boot application with Camel. When the application runs, it can get bean which is configured as a @Component

```
@Component("agencyExporterProcessor")
public class AgencyExporterProcessor {}
```

and I get the bean like this :

```
 from(getTriggerExportEndpoint())
            .routeId(getTriggerExportId())
            // When shutting down, Camel will wait until the batch completed
            .shutdownRunningTask(ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteAllTasks)
            .log("[SamCustomExporter] - RouteId:${routeId} - Begin at ${date:now:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}")
            .setHeader(Messaging.Names.SAM_DATA_AGENCY_CONFIGURATION_HEADER_KEY.toString(), constant(getConfiguration()))

            // Initialize a list to store exported CSV file names
            .bean(agencyExporterProcessor, "prepareExportedFileList")
```

But when I test, the route cannot get the bean"

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route agencyExporterRoute_triggerExport at: >>> Bean[ref:agencyExporterProcessor method:prepareExportedFileList] <<< in route: Route(agencyExporterRoute_triggerExport)[[From[direct:agency... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: agencyExporterProcessor
```

This is how I configured my unit test class:

```
@DirtiesContext
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootTest(classes = SamCustomExporterSpringApplication.class, 
webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class AgencyExporterRouteTest extends BaseRouteTestSupport {}
```

Please give advice!!!! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the bean name as a `String` value in the Camel route:

```
.bean("agencyExporterProcessor", "prepareExportedFileList")
```

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake when I copied the code. Yes I did like you already Mr Ibsen. But it still has this error

Comment: base package should be same for component scan . What is the package location for both the classes ?